# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized in vb.net and access

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class frmAddBook

    Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    Private Sub loadData()
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\LibrarySystem.accdb"
            'open connection
            cnn.Open()
        End If

        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT StatusID, FROM BookStatus", cnn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        'fill data to datatable
        da.Fill(dt)
        'show data in data table into combobox
        Me.cmbBookStatus.DataSource = dt
        Me.cmbBookStatus.DisplayMember = "StatusID"
        Me.cmbBookStatus.ValueMember = "StatusID"

        'close connection
        cnn.Close()

    End Sub

 Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If

        If (txtBookID.Text = "" And txtBookTitle.Text = "" And txtPub.Text = "" And txtAuthor.Text = "" And cmbBookStatus.SelectedValue = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert all field!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            Dim msgbox As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save this record?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

            If msgbox = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                'add new data
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                cmd.Connection = cnn
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Book(BookID, Title, Publisher, Author, StatusID) " & _
                " VALUES('" & txtBookID.Text & "','" & txtBookTitle.Text & "','" & txtPub.Text & "','" & txtAuthor.Text & "','" & cmbBookStatus.SelectedValue & "')"

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                MessageBox.Show("Data has been recorded", "Add New Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                txtBookID.Clear()
                txtBookTitle.Clear()
                txtPub.Clear()
                txtAuthor.Clear()

            End If

            'refresh data          
            'Me.loadData()

            Dim db As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Book", cnn)
            Dim dt As New DataTable

            'fill data to datatable
            db.Fill(dt)
            'show data in data table into datagridview
            Me.dgvAddBook.DataSource = dt

            Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = dgvAddBook.Columns(1)
            column.Width = 269
        End If

        'close connection
        cnn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDel.Click
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If

        If (txtBookID.Text = "" And txtBookTitle.Text = "" And txtPub.Text = "" And txtAuthor.Text = "" And cmbBookStatus.SelectedValue = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose record to be deleted", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            Dim msgbox As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete this record?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

            If msgbox = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                'add new data
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                cmd.Connection = cnn
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Book WHERE BookID = '" & txtBookID.Text & "'"

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                MessageBox.Show("Data has been deleted", "Delete Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                txtBookID.Clear()
                txtBookTitle.Clear()
                txtPub.Clear()
                txtAuthor.Clear()
            End If

            'refresh data          
            Me.loadData()
        End If

        'close connection
        cnn.Close()
    End Sub
```

I use visual studio 2010 and microsoft access. When i tried to add new data and save it, this error came out;

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been
>   initialized.

Can someone help me? I don't know what or where went wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: post your error message.

Comment: @chinna_82 This is the error message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: Can you print out the connection string, I'm thinking about the Application.StartupPath.

Comment: Does it get the data first time, and then it stops working? Or it just never works?